# How can I install ghostscript to work with PHP and imagegick so I can convert pdf files to png images

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, ghostscript, php-ini

Ok , I'm really confused .. I installed Imagemagick on XAMPP and it got installed successfully after running the phpinfo() function ... However , I'm not sure how to link ghostscript to PHP because I installed ghostscript on my computer and it's installed as a normal software having a UI like other programs on my desktop and I don't think that's how it's supposed to be ... How should I link it to PHP so imagemagick can detect it , like should I modify the apache file and php.ini .. if so , what should I put in there ?  what exact file should should I download to install ghostscript ?

Thanks a bunch !!

Comment: windows, linux, other ?

Comment: windows ... not using the commandline .. just manually

Comment: On Windows GS comes in 2 flavours, the GUI version gswin32 (or gswin64 if you installed the 64-bit version) and the command line version gswin32c.exe. Both behave identically, the only difference is that one runs in a command shell, the other has a window. The installer installs both executables so you don't have to do anything special. I've never tried ImageMagick under Windows (didn't know it was available) so I have no idea how you tell it where the binary is.

Answer (score 0):

you can run both imagemagick and ghostscript as shell commands like this

for Ghostscript :

```
echo exec('gswin64 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=d:\pdf\6.pdf -dBATCH ');
```

For Imagemagick

```
echo exec('convert -colorspace sRGB -quality 195% ');
```

now you will have to search for the right parameters to covert PDFs,optimize and merge them 
and as @kens said you will use gswin32c.exe as a command shell and gswin32.exe to show the output in 
the GS tool it self